# Does iOS have a built in file manager?

Tags: ios, filesystem

Does iOS 10.2.1 have a built in file manager?  If so, where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.  A goal of iOS is to remove the idea of files and folders and allow the user to focus simply on their data and accessing it whenever they want and wherever they are.

If you need a file manager, you'll need to jailbreak first and then use a myriad of 3rd-party file managers available.

Answer (score 1):

Because in iOS, the app is the starting point for all concepts, the file is not, the concept of "file" is not even allowed to exist, so there is no File Manager.

After using iOS, compared to other systems, everything is so simple. Go to the AppStore, find the software, click on the download, it's so simple, you can use it, some simple and clear. As for the modification of the software and the cracking of the game itself is not allowed, Apple can not tolerate the system caused by non-technical reasons.

So if you want a file manager in iOS, you have to jailbreak your iphone.